# Как мне здесь найти нужный мне ответ на вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, поиск

Здесь мне как-то встретилась очень интересная реализация скрытия части элементов. На примере майл.ру, где показывается только три похожие новости, а при нажатии на кнопку, показываются все остальные. Очень жалею, что не добавил в избранное этот вопрос, а сейчас не могу его найти.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском по сайту по фразам вроде "подгрузка новостей" и т.д.

Comment: Как-то так: [`mail.ru is:q -письм* -почт* -smtp -api -авторизац*`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mail.ru+is%3Aq+-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC*+-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82*+-smtp+-api+-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86*+%5Bjavascript%5D), только допилить напильником до желаемых результатов.

Comment: В будущем, когда вам понравится вопрос, добавляйте его в избранное с помощью кнопки-звезды под стрелками слева от вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь страницей поиска по сайту: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search.

Подробная информация о том как сформировать поисковый запрос есть в справке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching.